# Center/Set Zoom of Map to cover all visible Markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am setting multiple markers on my map and I can set statically the zoom levels and the center but what I want is, to cover all the markers and zoom as much as possible having all markets visible

Available methods are following

[`setZoom(zoom:number)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

and

[`setCenter(latlng:LatLng)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Neither `setCenter` supports multiple location or Location array input nor `setZoom` does have this type of functionality

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362337/how-to-set-the-google-map-zoom-level-to-show-all-the-markers

Comment: you need to add the `latlng` to a `bounds` object each time you add a marker and set your map to fit the final bounds. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center?rq=1

Answer (score 760, accepted):

You need to use the `fitBounds()` method.

```
var markers = [];//some array
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 bounds.extend(markers[i]);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

---

**Documentation** from [developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds):

> ### **`fitBounds(bounds[, padding])`**
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> `bounds`:  [`LatLngBounds`][1]|[`LatLngBoundsLiteral`][1]
> `padding` (optional):  number|[`Padding`][1]
> ```
>
> **Return Value:**  None
>
> Sets the viewport to contain the given bounds.
>   **Note**: When the map is set to `display: none`, the `fitBounds` function reads the map's size as `0x0`, and therefore does not do anything. To change the viewport while the map is hidden, set the map to `visibility: hidden`, thereby ensuring the map div has an actual size.

Comment: From where did the `getPosition` method came from?

Comment: @Pratheep - it's part of the google.maps.Marker class; https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: Just as an aside for the newbies out there, with the same question as Pratheep... You know this if you're experienced with the Maps API, but you can always pass in a `LatLngLiteral` instead of having a Marker instance. e.g., `bounds.extend({lat: 123, lng: 456})`.

Comment: For some reason when I iterate through an array of markers, `getPosition` always returns undefined. I fixed this by calling `bounds.extend` every time I create a marker.

Comment: An extra tip for anyone interested. You can define a padding by using `fitBounds(bounds, int)` which will allow you to have a little space between the markers and the map edges (or less space if you need). [See Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds)

Comment: map.fitBounds(bounds); solved everything!! Banging my head for the past 2 hours. Thanks

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this in wordpress google maps? I am to display the markers but I'm looking for auto-zoom/fit-bounds?

Comment: I found that calling `fitBounds()` after the loop where I add markers caused it to execute prematurely due to the process being asychronous. If this is the case for you, call `fitBounds()` on the final loop iteration.

Answer (score 203):

To extend the given answer with few useful tricks:

```
var markers = //some array;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
}

//center the map to a specific spot (city)
map.setCenter(center); 

//center the map to the geometric center of all markers
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

map.fitBounds(bounds);

//remove one zoom level to ensure no marker is on the edge.
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1); 

// set a minimum zoom 
// if you got only 1 marker or all markers are on the same address map will be zoomed too much.
if(map.getZoom()> 15){
  map.setZoom(15);
}

//Alternatively this code can be used to set the zoom for just 1 marker and to skip redrawing.
//Note that this will not cover the case if you have 2 markers on the same address.
if(count(markers) == 1){
    map.setMaxZoom(15);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.setMaxZoom(Null)
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Further research in the topic show that fitBounds() is a asynchronic
and it is best to make Zoom manipulation with a listener defined before calling Fit Bounds.
Thanks @Tim, @xr280xr, more examples on the topic : [SO:setzoom-after-fitbounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437683/google-maps-api-v3-can-i-setzoom-after-fitbounds)

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
  this.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1);

  if (this.getZoom() > 15) {
    this.setZoom(15);
  }
});
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: I was having undefined returned by .getZoom(). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13435411/263832) helped me solve it by using `addListenerOnce` on `zoom_changed` to set the zoom after its value has been initialized.

Comment: Thanks @d.raev but setting the max zoom when boundaries are already set doesn't work. What you must do is set the "maxZoom" option when initializing your map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions

Comment: In the part about the zoom manipulation (**UPDATE**), you're mixing a couple vars and scopes. You use `yourMap`, `map` and `this`. Maybe it's a good idea to make it more consistent.

Answer (score 14):

The size of array must be greater than zero.
Οtherwise you will have unexpected results.

```
function zoomeExtends(){
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  if (markers.length>0) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
        }    
        myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is this `MarkerClusterer` client side utility available for google Map as specified here on [*Google Map developer Articles*](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers), here is brief on what's it's usage:

There are many approaches for doing what you asked for:

- Grid based clustering
- Distance based clustering
- Viewport Marker Management
- Fusion Tables
- Marker Clusterer
- MarkerManager

You can read about them on the provided link above.

[`Marker Clusterer`](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) uses *Grid Based Clustering* to cluster all the marker wishing the grid. Grid-based clustering works by dividing the map into squares of a certain size (the size changes at each zoom) and then grouping the markers into each grid square.

Before Clustering
[image: Before Clustering]

After Clustering
[image: After Clustering]

I hope this is what you were looking for & this will solve your problem :)