# Smart zoom in Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Need help with this task:
The screen is divided into two parts. On the right we show the list of added addresses. On the left we show the map with points on this addresses.
The task is to show all the labels, but... It is necessary to choose a zoom in such a way as to show the last 10 added addresses on the map.

Sorry for my English.

Regards, Evgeny!

Comment: Please add what you tried so far

Comment: `The task is` - assignment?

Comment: I add map and add markers for all addresses. Now i have coordinates of 10 latest added addresses. Me need center and zoom map based on this 10 coords.

Comment: Can you share your map's javascript/jQuery code of plotting markers on the map?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304574/center-set-zoom-of-map-to-cover-all-visible-markers

Comment: I need not for all, but i think fitBounds() method help me. Big thanks, Nicholas!