# Find center and zoom into all LatLng

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, flutter, dart

I have multiple `LatLng`
Using this library: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter
how can I get their center and zoom into the map so that all the `LatLng` are visible, but not too far from the screen?

Answer (score -2):

I found this on a similar question so I hope it applies... ([Center/Set Zoom of Map to cover all visible Markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304574/center-set-zoom-of-map-to-cover-all-visible-markers))

```
var markers = [];//some array
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 bounds.extend(markers[i]);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Possibly take a look at their documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds

Comment: Thanks, saw that answer before, but I don't think flutters librry has `extend`