# Google maps api V3 this is undefined error on getCenter() after ajax added

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to update search results by ajax after map dragged. 
Here is code that I am using.

```
function initMap(){
var locations = [];
var count = 0;
$('.oneListing').each(function(){
    locations[count] = {title:$(this).html(),lat: $(this).data('lat'), lng: $(this).data('lng')};
    count ++;
})

window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['lng']),
        map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i]['title']);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);

var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
    map.setZoom(4);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});

    map.addListener('dragend', function() {
        var zoom = map.getZoom();
        var center = map.getCenter();
        updatesearch(center, zoom);
    });
}
function updatesearch(center, zoom){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/searches/update',
        type: 'post',
        data: {zoom: zoom,center: center},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
        }            
    })
}
```

after this I am getting error saying `TypeError: this is undefined` its happening on getCenter() function. 
What can cause this kind of error and what can I do to avoid it.
I am using jquery v1.11.1
Let me know if other information needed. 
This error appearing only after i am trying to do ajax call to my back end to get new items. Otherwise getCenter() returning right result.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434750/maps-api-v3-getcenter-and-getzoom-not-working

Comment: I think situation is not the same . In his case he lost content of his variable or dont get it . in my case i am getting error just after I put in code ajax to call back end. Otherwise i am getting centre latlng pretty fine.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put it in question , question updated.

Comment: So you are saying the error doesn't occur if you remove the call to `updatesearch` in your dragend listener? If so, try replacing that with an alert of center. Change `updatesearch(center, zoom);` to `alert(center);` to see if it's still undefined.

Comment: Yes in that case i am getting right latlng , even if i am not commenting function call but just commenting ajax call from it and instead it alerting center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.
getCenter() is returning object not string , that's why after using variable in data of ajax I was getting that error . 
The sollution is to call lat() and lng() functions on center variable , and then pass it to ajax.