# Google maps api spits errors for markers and markerclusters

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
window.initMap=function() {
var options = {
  zoom: 3,
  center: {lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887}
}
var ourmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);

// Add some markers to the map.
// Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
// create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
// The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
    setMap: ourmap,
    position: locations
});

// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
    {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

locations is declared underneath as an array of coordinates. I keep getting a crap ton of errors that say "this.map_.getZoom is not a function" in the file js?key=MYAPIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap

Comment: search for the error in google ... first two results ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434750/maps-api-v3-getcenter-and-getzoom-not-working and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/Q27GYsOtccM

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's something wrong with your new marker function.
What setMap is?

Try to write the following, i test it and it worked without errors for me.

```
        function initMap() {

        var options = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: { lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887 }
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
    }
```